Auth0 Issue with refresh tokens
We are have problems with auth0 tokens in next.js app hosted on vercel.
We get ~10 errors “Unknown or invalid refresh token.” every minute (DAU is 500).
{
  "date": "2024-04-29T10:07:51.251Z",
  "type": "fertft",
  "description": "Unknown or invalid refresh token.",
  "connection_id": "",
  "client_id": "X",
  "client_name": "Humy",
  "ip": "X",
  "user_agent": "Other 0.0.0 / Other 0.0.0",
  "hostname": "X",
  "user_id": "",
  "user_name": "",
  "auth0_client": {
    "name": "nextjs-auth0",
    "version": "3.5.0",
    "env": {
      "node": "v18.20.0"
    }
  },
  "$event_schema": {
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "log_id": "90020240429100751283450000000000000001223372040544496478",
  "_id": "90020240429100751283450000000000000001223372040544496478",
  "isMobile": false,
  "id": "90020240429100751283450000000000000001223372040544496478"
}

Login and Logout however are working.
Our Assumption
We assume we haven’t configured the auth0/sdk properly and
It doesn’t refresh expired ID or Access tokens.
Auth0 Instance:
Auth0 app: Regular Web Application
ID Token Expiration: 2592000
Refresh Token Rotation: OFF
Refresh Token Expiration: ON
Absolute Expiration: ON
Inactivity Expiration: ON
Authentication Methods: Client Secret (POST)
Advanced settings - 0Auth
Algorithm: RS256
OIDC Conformant: ON
Advanced settings - grant types
Implicit, Authorisation code, Refresh Token
How we are using next.js:

Vercel as a Hosting.
next 14.1.0
@auth0/nextjs-auth0 v3.5.0 (latest)

We are using withPageAuthRequired and withApiAuthReqired to protect the pages and routes
List of scopes in handleLogin

openid
profile
email
offline_access

List of scopes in getAccessToken

openid
offline_access

Questions:

Why we are getting “Unknown or invalid refresh token.” and how to fix it?
Does the refresh token expiration time have to be the same as ID Token/Access Token expiration?
Auto logout when access token expires works on localhost but not in development url (which has  NODE_ENV === “production”), is that caused by using development tenant keys production?

